# Issue with merging JSON files with uneven fields

Tags: python, json

I am trying to merge **multiple JSON files** of **some size**, and uneven fields.

Here is what i mean:

**JSON Example#1**

```
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}
```

**JSON Example#2**

```
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "middleName":"Doe"}
```

Both the files are saved in the same location as the Merger.py that i am using merge these 2 JSON files.

***Merger.py***

```
import json
import glob

result = []
for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        result.append(json.load(infile))

with open("merged_file.json", "wb") as outfile:
     json.dump(result, outfile)
```

When i try to execute it however, i keep getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "Merger.py", line 10, in 
>       json.dump(result, outfile)
>     File "C:\Users\<...Directory Path...>\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json__init__.py",
>   line 180, in dump
>       fp.write(chunk) TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I understand this is due to uneven fields in the JSON files.

My question is, is there a work around for this situation ?

The original files are consisting of 91+ Million records each, so manual merging is out of the question *(not that i have not tried that too)*.

Comment: Don't open and write bytes. Use 'r' (read) when you load it and 'w' (write) when you write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand this is due to uneven fields in the JSON files.

No,this is not problem.

You use `with open(f, "rb") as infile` and `open("merged_file.json", "wb")`.
That is incorrect.
You should use `with open(f, "r") as infile` and `open("merged_file.json", "w")`.

Only when we open a binary file instead of a text file,we use `wb` or `rb`.

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

The exception has shown your problem.

So you code maybe should be this:

```
import json

result = []
for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open(f, "r") as infile:
        result.append(json.load(infile))

Yourjson = {
    "result":result
}

with open("merged_file.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(Yourjson, outfile,indent=4)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File "Merger.py", line 7, in <module> result.append(json.load(infile)) File "C:\...\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook,**kw)
File "C:\...\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s) File "C:\...\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode obj, end = self.raw_decode(s,idx=_w(s, 0).end()) File "C:\...\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:Expecting value:line 1 column 1

Comment: @404BrainNotFound I edit my answer,you can try to use my answer.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):File "Merger.py", line 7, in <module>result.append(json.load(infile)) File "C:\...\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw) File "C:\...\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s) File "C:\...\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end()) File "C:\...\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1

Comment: @404BrainNotFound Can you show me your ``result`` variable?

Comment: @404BrainNotFound I use ``result = [{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "middleName":"Doe"}]`` to test and can run it without exception.

Comment: Your solution is correct, merging of files are now taking place without any errors/exceptions, but i think the result is still not getting accepted as a valid json. I am not sure if the magnitude of the data in the files i am merging has something to do with it.